# Generating Paths and URLs from Code in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I put this in route.rb  `get '/products/:id', to: 'products#edit'` edit action should be called when the url format is `/patients/:id` does this mean it will be redirected to edit page? I tried this and it is not redirecting.

This is my rake routes output

```
admin GET    /admin(.:format)                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin"}
                   GET    /products/:id(.:format)                      {:controller=>"products", :action=>"edit"}
             login GET    /login(.:format)                             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
                   POST   /login(.:format)                             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
            logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
             users GET    (/:locale)/users(.:format)                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                   POST   (/:locale)/users(.:format)                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
          new_user GET    (/:locale)/users/new(.:format)               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
         edit_user GET    (/:locale)/users/:id/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
              user GET    (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                   PUT    (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                   DELETE (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
            orders GET    (/:locale)/orders(.:format)                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"orders"}
                   POST   (/:locale)/orders(.:format)                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"orders"}
         new_order GET    (/:locale)/orders/new(.:format)              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"orders"}
        edit_order GET    (/:locale)/orders/:id/edit(.:format)         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"orders"}
             order GET    (/:locale)/orders/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orders"}
                   PUT    (/:locale)/orders/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"update", :controller=>"orders"}
                   DELETE (/:locale)/orders/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"orders"}
        line_items GET    (/:locale)/line_items(.:format)              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"line_items"}
                   POST   (/:locale)/line_items(.:format)              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"line_items"}
     new_line_item GET    (/:locale)/line_items/new(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"line_items"}
    edit_line_item GET    (/:locale)/line_items/:id/edit(.:format)     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"line_items"}
         line_item GET    (/:locale)/line_items/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items"}
                   PUT    (/:locale)/line_items/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"line_items"}
                   DELETE (/:locale)/line_items/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"line_items"}
             carts GET    (/:locale)/carts(.:format)                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"carts"}
                   POST   (/:locale)/carts(.:format)                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"carts"}
          new_cart GET    (/:locale)/carts/new(.:format)               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"carts"}
         edit_cart GET    (/:locale)/carts/:id/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"carts"}
              cart GET    (/:locale)/carts/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carts"}
                   PUT    (/:locale)/carts/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"carts"}
                   DELETE (/:locale)/carts/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"carts"}
who_bought_product GET    (/:locale)/products/:id/who_bought(.:format) {:action=>"who_bought", :controller=>"products"}
          products GET    (/:locale)/products(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"products"}
                   POST   (/:locale)/products(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"products"}
       new_product GET    (/:locale)/products/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"products"}
      edit_product GET    (/:locale)/products/:id/edit(.:format)       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"products"}
           product GET    (/:locale)/products/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products"}
                   PUT    (/:locale)/products/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"products"}
                   DELETE (/:locale)/products/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"products"}
             store        /(:locale)(.:format)                         {:controller=>"store", :action=>"index"}
```

Comment: how are you redirecting to edit page ? `redirect_to` or `link_to` ?

Comment: This is not redirecting. If you send request from one action to to other by using redirect_to than it call redirects the one you are trying is mapping of this URL to your edit action for patients controller

Comment: I encourage you to read [rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: You dont seem to have any route to the patients controller at all.

Answer (score 1):

The route you've got there doesn't do a redirect, it maps the url `/patients/:id` to the `edit` action of the `PatientsController`.

When a user hits the `/patients/id` url, the `edit` action will be invoked. By default this tries to render a view with the same name as the action.

If you want to render an edit page, create a view in the `/app/views/patients` folder called `edit.html.erb`.

(By the way, the `GET /model/:id` route is generally used for the `show` action.)

Comment: I know it is used for show action but I am learning rails and wanted to try this out. I already have edit.html.erb but it is not rendering it. Show action is invoked here.

Comment: Can you add the output of `rake routes` to your question?

Comment: added the rake routes

Comment: Patient isn't defined in your rake routes posted above. Can you make sure to include the patient path in your routes? If it really isn't found in your rake routes, then it likely isn't defined in your routes.rb file.

Comment: sorry it will be /products/:id

Comment: Have you defined the "edit" action in your controller?